# TreelistEx field with Search

Tags: search, lucene, sitecore, treelist

I have a requirement from a client to modify the treelistex field to include a search box on top of the left content tree list box. This will allow searching of items instead of the user having to click through the content tree. This Sitecore installation has pages numbering in the thousands hence clicking through takes time and knowing where the page item exists.

How can I achieve this functionality? I will use the _system Lucene index from Sitecore to search the various items. The items need to be search based on item name, title field, content field and date fields.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interestingly, something just like this was posted to Shared Source the other day! Check out the [Specialized Treelist](http://trac.sitecore.net/SpecializedTreelist) from Shared Source.

> Search using the built in Sitecore Lucene indexes

[image]